# OpenLayers 2 loadstart and loadend

Tags: openlayers-2, event-listener

I want to add a loading symbol to my openlayers map, which is triggered when a layer is set to load and stopped when the layer is loaded. So I used the event listeners loadstart and loaded. Here is my code so far to load the layer:

```
    uf300 = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("UF Notfall", {
            projection: toProjection,
            styleMap: style_uf300,
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: "/GeoJSON/uf_hq300.geojson",
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
            })
        }); 

LoadingCircle(uf300);
```

The event listener is in this function:

```
function LoadingCircle(layer) {

    layer.events.register("loadstart", layer, function o() {
        markers.clearMarkers(); 
        var lonlat1 = map.getCenter();
        var circle = new OpenLayers.Marker(lonlat1,icon1);
        markers.addMarker(circle);
    });         
    layer.events.register("loadend", layer, function p() {
        markers.clearMarkers();
        lonlat1=null;
        circle=null;        
    });
```

Unfortunately this only works when the layer is selected for the first time. When the user makes the layer invisible and then visible again the symbol won't show.

I tried refreshing and destroying the layer when the user makes it invisible, and also tried 3 different types of calling the event listener. Unfortunately nothing worked...

How can I start running the loading symbol every time the user decides to make the layer visible?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add an animation on event:

```
visibilitychanged
```

There is no reason for adding events on create/destroy layer, I think.

Comment: I thought of that too, but I couldn't think of a way to stop showing the loading symbol without the 'loadend' event. With visibilitychanged I can only start the loading symbol

Comment: So, you can try this steps: show animation when "featureselected" event of Vector layer throwed, and hide animation on callback of Protocol.Http

Comment: Good idea. I am going to give a try. Might take a while, as I am currently burried in work :)

Comment: Sure, I hope this will be work :)